# Как ускорить работу исполнителя чертёжник в Pascal ABC

Tags: pascalabc.net

Осваиваем с ребенком Pascal ABC (школьный курс информатики - 6 класс).

Написали программку, которая рисует некий орнамент из квадратиков.
Рисование одного квадратика оформили как процедуру.
Рисование повторяющихся фигурок из квадратиков также оформили как процедуру.
Рисование строки из повторяющихся фигурок из квадратиков также оформили как процедуру.
Заполнение квадратной области строками из повторяющихся фигурок из квадратиков также оформили как процедуру. И так далее... Итого получилась глубина вложения процедур - 8 уровней.

В итоге процедура рисования квадратика вызывается 3645 раз.
В исполнителе Чертежник ползунок скорости выставлен на максимум.
Но отрисовка орнамента очень долгая.
Вот фрагмент орнамента и таких фрагментов - 9

[image]

Вопрос - можно ли как-то ускорить работу чертежника?

Comment: Не знаю, что такое "чертежник", но попробуйте выяснить, нельзя ли нарисовать кусок Вашего "фрактала" в битмап, а потом вывести этот битмап нужное количество раз.

Comment: Без кода не разбраться.

Comment: Чертежник - это учебная программа, потому не рассчитана на большие узоры. Все задания от разработчиков не очень объемные и потому решаются быстро, поле обычно 20 на 20 не больше, а то и меньше. Для рисования подобного узора лучше перейдите в графику. В ней отрисовка мгновенная, если намеренно не ставить замедление.

Comment: Конечно это не совсем то, что вам нужно, но вашу фигуру можно нарисовать одной непрерывной ломаной, а не пятью квадратами. Это сократит количество шагов более чем в два раза.

Answer (score 1):

### Спасибо всем откликнувшимся.
Ответы немного не о том, о чем был вопрос, но тем не менее...

Ответ на свой вопрос нашел сам (случайно ;).
В файле Х:\PABCWork.NET\ABC.ini  значение параметра Speed было 10. Заменил на 1000 и орнамент стал отрисовываться в разы быстрее. И в свойствах файла установил [только чтение] - иначе как только сдвинешь ползунок скорости, так значение  Speed в ini-файле возвращается к значению 10

```
[DrawmanWindow]
Height=1440
Left=398
Speed=1000
Top=274
Width=1247
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример предоставленный разработчиками PascalABC.Net. Работа не с Чертежником, а с графическим модулем GraphABC

```pascal
// Пример из пакета KuMir/PMir
program Dragon;

uses GraphABC, Utils;

var
    x := 200;
    y := 150;
    dx := 0;
    dy := -4;
    turn: array [1..1000] of Boolean;

begin
    SetWindowSize(790, 500);
    Window.Title := 'Кривая Дракона';
    var f := True;
    for var a := 1 to 64 do
    begin
        turn[2 * a - 1] := f;
        f := not f;
        turn[2 * a] := turn[a];
    end;
    var b := 0;
    var d := 1;
    f := false;
    MoveTo(x, y);
    
    for var a := 1 to 128 do
    begin
        var t: integer;
        LockDrawing;
        for var i := 1 to 127 * 4 do
        begin
            b += d; 
            x += dx; 
            y += dy;
            LineTo(x, y);
            if f and not turn[b] or not f and turn[b] then
            begin
                t := dy;
                dy := -dx;
            end
            else
            begin
                t := -dy;
                dy := dx;
            end;
            dx := t;
        end;
        b += d; 
        x += dx; 
        y += dy;
        LineTo(x, y);
        d := -d;
        f := not f;
        if turn[a] then
        begin
            t := dy;
            dy := -dx;
        end
        else
        begin
            t := -dy;
            dy := dx;
        end;
        dx := t;
        UnLockDrawing;
    end;
    write('Время работы = ', Milliseconds / 1000, ' с');
end.
```